# Doubts on some words in a Deng Lijun song

Tags: pronunciation, lyrics

I just listened to the song [无奈](https://youtu.be/U4FpyBBFhlE) by Deng Lijun, and there are three points where what I hear doesn't match the lyrics I have:

1. At the end of the sentence at 1:30-1:37, my lyrics have 痴情 | chïqíng, but I hear either qiqi or qiqing;
2. The 仍藏心底 | réng cáng xïn dî at 2:59-3:01 sounds to me like ying can xin di;
3. The 选择 | xuânzé in the sentence at 3:14-3:18 and 3:27-3:31 sounds like suanjia to me, and given that shortly before we have a 选择 which actually sounds like xuanze I am fairly certain it must be another word.

Is that all just me mishearing or am I on to something?

Also, another video of the song has 00:41-00:47 captioned as 看着你一脸惘然 眼眶是泪滴, my lyrics have 看着你一脸茫然 眼眶是泪滴, and I'm not sure if I hear mangran or mengran. Can you confirm my lyrics have it right? Is 一脸茫然 a chengyu?

Comment: https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/195615757.html  check this version, it seems to match all what you hear

Comment: @JasonSwift Almost. There is the 惘 which AFAIK is wâng but I hear mang/meng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my conclusions:

1. The 痴情 is supposed to be 戚戚 | qi1qi1, as suggested [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/195615757.html);
2. The 仍藏心底 is supposed to be 隐藏心底 | yin3cang2 xin1 di3, as suggested [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/195615757.html);
3. The 选择 at the end is supposed to be 三角 | san1jiao4, as suggested [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/195615757.html);
4. The 惘然 is supposed to be 茫然; I only draw this conclusion because it seems to me "blank" fits the context better than "suddenly", since "your face is blank and there is tears in your eyes" is what would result from 茫然, whereas with 猛然 you would have "on the whole face" (一脸) and "the eyes" (眼眶), two contradictory complements of place.

The three "here"s above all link to the same link provided in [Jason Swift's comment](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29738/doubts-on-some-words-in-a-deng-lijun-song#comment42663_29738).